# Subtraction in a spreadsheet column numbering scheme

Tags: javascript, algorithm, strings, number-systems

**The idea of the algorithm is to decrease a number from a word.**

Is there a better way to write this algorithm?

limitiation:

- it is important to decrease with a limit, if BB is the word we
  decrease from, after decreasing by 1 the result will be BA, but
  after decreasing by 2, we expect logically for the result to be AZ,
  but no, we want to stay with our word limit, so the result will be
  AB, the next word will be AA.
- tought it supports decreasing only it can be changed easily to
  support increasing.
- though it supports only UPPER CASE letters, it can be changed easily
  by changing the A_IN_ASCII code.

Usage:

one usage that was needed, was to create a matrix based on a start cell and an end cell - the start cell is AA and the end cell is BB, so we will need those cells : (AA, AB, BA, BB), to get them we need to decrease from BB by an increasing index 0

Examples:

```
 - getWordDecreasedByNumber('C', 2) = 'A' (just like doing 3 - 2 = 1)
 - getWordDecreasedByNumber('AB', 1) = 'AA' ('AB' - 1)
 - getWordDecreasedByNumber('BB', 3) = 'AA' ('BB' - 3)
 - getWordDecreasedByNumber('ZZ', 26*26-1) = 'AA' ('ZZ' - 675)
 - getWordDecreasedByNumber('ZZZZ', 25) = 'ZZZA' ('ZZZZ' - 25)
 - getWordDecreasedByNumber('ZZZZ', 26) = 'ZZYZ' ('ZZZZ' - 26)
 - getWordDecreasedByNumber('BB', 1) = 'BA'
 - getWordDecreasedByNumber('BB', 2) = 'AB'
 - getWordDecreasedByNumber('BB', 3) = 'AA'
```

Code:

```js
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
}

function getWordDecreasedByNumber(word, n) {
            var A_IN_ASCII = 64;
            var decreasedWord = word;
            for (var i = word.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var limit = (word.charCodeAt(i) - A_IN_ASCII);
                var reduce = n % limit;
                var newCode = word.charCodeAt(i) - reduce;
                var newChar = String.fromCharCode(newCode);
                decreasedWord = decreasedWord.replaceAt(i, newChar);
                n = Math.floor((n - reduce) / limit);
            }

            return decreasedWord;
   }



 console.info(getWordDecreasedByNumber('C', 2)) // 'A'
 console.info(getWordDecreasedByNumber('AB', 1)) // 'AA'
 console.info(getWordDecreasedByNumber('BB', 3)) //'AA'
 console.info(getWordDecreasedByNumber('ZZ', 26*26-1)) //'AA' ('ZZ' - 675)
 console.info(getWordDecreasedByNumber('ZZZZ', 25)) //'ZZZA'
 console.info(getWordDecreasedByNumber('ZZZZ', 26)) //'ZZYZ'
 console.info(getWordDecreasedByNumber('BB', 1)) // 'BA'
 console.info(getWordDecreasedByNumber('BB', 2)) // 'AB'
 console.info(getWordDecreasedByNumber('BB', 3)) // 'AA'
```

Comment: wouldn't BB - 3 be AY? see [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/tFcLOJL.png)

Comment: No, the requirement is to have this limitation. Look at the limitation section.

Comment: sorry, missed that.  can you explain how the numbering should work in English so the requirements don't have to be reverse engineered from the code and test cases?